# Azure Data Factory - Data Flow - Derived Column Issue

Tags: azure-data-factory

Am using Azure DataFlow - DerivedColumn to create some new columns.

Ex:

[image]

this is my source and can preview the data.

But from DerivedColumn1 i cannot see these column or even in Expression Editor

[image]

Expression Editor:

[image]

Is something changed in ADF or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: How about delete the Derived Column and add again?Just from your screen, please set the first row as header in excel dataaset.

Comment: Some other solution is create a new data flow. It may be a bug.

Comment: Hi @Sreedhad, is the error solved now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According you screenshot, the column name is set as the row. Or you will get the error in Sink column mapping. Please set "first row as header" in the excel dataset.
[image]

If you don't check it, the column name will be considered as first row:
[image]

For your issue, you could try bellow workarounds:

1. import the source schema in Projection and Delete the Derived column
   active and add again.
2. Drop the data flow and create a new one. Some time data flow may
   have bugs, we refresh the browser or just recreate the data flow, it
   will be solved.

Comment: Yes it only works if i import source schema in Projection tab.

Comment: @Sreedhar derived column get the schema from input stream(source), just import it in source. So, the issue is solved now? If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.